# postcss vulnerability in @vue/cli-service

Tags: javascript, vue.js, security, dependencies

**The issue :**
I have more than 100 vulnerabilities due to @vue/cli-service dependency to postcss.
And i have 50 more between postcss and @quasar/app

**What I've tried :**

- npm audit fix didn't work.
- Updating @vue/cli-service to its last version seems to work but this version is in beta so I don't want it in production. Same with @quasar/app.

Here's an example of that vulnerability

[image]

Comment: It is because the older version of postcss is not supported, see below link https://www.npmjs.com/advisories/1693

Many packages are internally dependent on postcss and they haven't updated postcss versions. Thus you are getting these vulnerabilities.